# Is $(Pf)(x)=(f(x)+f(−x))/2$ a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Lang's Introduction to Linear Algebra there is this exercise:

> Let $V$ be  the  vector  space  of all  functions.  Define  the  map
>   $$P: V \to V$$ by $$(Pf)(x) = (f(x) + f( -x))/2$$
>
> Show  that  P  is  a  linear  map.

If my understanding is correct, $P$ is a linear map when for all functions $f$ and all values of $x$ the mapping is linear (this is where I might be wrong). But if I take the function $f(x) = 1$, then $(Pf)(ax) = 1$, but $a(Pf)(x) = a$. So $P$ is not a linear map.

Comment: $Pf$ is not necessarily a linear map, but $P$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mistaken about what it means for $P$ to be a linear map; it is a mapping from a vector space to a vector space, so by linear map we mean that "adding in its domain" results in the same outcome as when "adding the results in the codomain", by which I mean:

$$ P(f+g) = P(f) + P(g).$$
Of course, $P(f+g)$ is a function (as is $P(f) + P(g)$), so what the equal-sign here means is exactly:

$$ (P(f+g))(x) = (Pf)(x) + (Pg)(x)$$
for all $x$, by the definition of adding functions in $V$. Additionally, to be linear, scalars have to be able to be 'pulled out':

$$ P(\lambda f) = \lambda P(f),$$
where the equal-sign again means:

$$ (P(\lambda f))(x) = \lambda (Pf)(x),$$
by the definition of how to multiply a function in $V$ with a scalar.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=af(x)=a$. Then $(Pf)(x)=(f(x)+f(-x))/2=1$ and
$(Pg)(x)=(g(x)+g(-x))/2=a$. Thus $Pg=a(Pf)$. So, where's the problem?